# Download Zip File from URL using Python

Tags: python, networking, python-zipfile

I'm trying to use the Requests module to download a ZIP file from my web server.

I've tried multiple different ways, but it always errors out.

My most recent code is promising - the downloaded file size is (close) to what I expect (it's a little more, somehow?), but when trying to unzip the file using Python I get this error:

```
    fp.seek(self.start_dir, 0)
    OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

and trying to open it using Windows 10 I get the "invalid ZIP file" error.

This is my current code:

```
LATEST_PACKAGE = requests.get(NET_URL + "/package.zip")
lp_local = open("%s:/Users/%s/Desktop/package.zip"%(DRIVELETTER, os.getlogin()), "xb")
lp_local.write(bytes(LATEST_PACKAGE.text, "UTF-8"))
lp_local.close()

with ZipFile("%s:/Users/%s/Desktop/package.zip"%(DRIVELETTER, os.getlogin())) as data:
   data.extractall(INSTALL_PATH)
   data.close()
```

where DRIVELETTER is the Windows 10 drive (in my case, C:/).

Can anyone provide any insight on this error, and any potential solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to try/use something else than "requests" and you don't need to store the archive (*just download and extract it; if you need to store it, let me know*), you can try to code below:

```
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen
from zipfile import ZipFile

zipurl = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1yAmFc15GtP52El_RTxl6uqmZZJi-h4BG'

with urlopen(zipurl) as zipresp:
    with ZipFile(BytesIO(zipresp.read())) as zfile:
        zfile.extractall('*YOUR PATH HERE*')
```

Result:

[image]

**Note:** if you need to store the archive let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm, and it's much faster than requests, too!